# Is $X\sim(\mathcal{N}(0,1))^2$ allowed?

Tags: probability

Am I allowed to say that $X\sim(\mathcal{N}(0,1))^2$? Or should I instead say $X=Y^2$ where $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

My question arises from the following: $\sigma\mathcal{N}(0,1)=\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

I am not really sure what kind of mathematical object $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is: am I allowed to take its square? Should I write $\sigma\mathcal{N}(0,1)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ instead?

Comment: The second statement is clear.  The first one looks ambiguous; it could be the same as the other statement, or it could be a multivariate distribution.

Comment: $X$ is a random variable and $N(0,1)$ is a distribution. So you should only use the second.

Comment: @skyking $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is as standard as it gets -- "standard Normal (Gaussian)" distribution. $(\mathcal{N}(0,1))^2$ is non-standard and seems wrong, however (is it the s"square of a probability distribution"? What is tha object now?" -- either introduce the notation, or write $X=Y^2$.

Comment: But incidentally, in this particular case $X\sim\chi^2_1$ ([Chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)), so go for *that* (standard) notation instead.

Comment: I think there's more to the question than just $(\mathcal N(0,1))^2$ seems wrong...

Comment: @skyking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Notation

Comment: @Shuri2060, you say $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is a distribution. What do you mean with that? Is it the probability density function? I doubt that. However, I would understand that taking the square does not make sense.

Comment: @ClementC. So **what** is $\mathbb N(0,1)$? That's a part of the question you see. And I think that would be a part of the description of why $(\mathbb N(0,1))^2$ is wrong, I don't think that it "seems wrong" is sufficient.

Comment: It is a probability distribution. It satisfies the axioms of a probability distribution. The operation "square" is not defined on the set of probability distributions, and for the notation suggested to make sense one would have to define it in a way that maps a probability distribution to another probability distribution. It is possible (the suggested meaning by the OP works), but it is **non-standard** -- one could interpret that notation as "take the pdf of a standard normal and square it," which would **not** result in a valid probability distribution.

Comment: @skyking If you understand what the notation $X\sim D$ **means** ($X$ follows the probability distribution $D$), then surely you agree that the RHS must **be** a probability distribution. So for the OP's notation to make sense, there should be an agreed-upon consensus, or introduced notation, for what $D^2$ is (and why it is a probability distribution) when $D$ is one.

Comment: ?? I don't get your point. You want to know what the object is, I answered: it is a probability distribution.  This is a well-defined mathematical object. Do you want me to reproduce here what axioms a probability distribution must satisfy?

Comment: @skyking Probability distribution $\equiv$ Nonnegative measure of unit mass. Axioms of probability distribution $\equiv$ Axioms of nonnegative measure + Axiom of total mass $1$.

Comment: @skyking Because these are not the same kind of mathematical object.

Comment: @skyking Why delete your comment?

Comment: @Did I'm satisfied with your answer, and it looks like the "what kind of object"-part of the question wasn't that important. I don't think the discussion adds much any longer.

Comment: @Clement I'm satisfied with Did's answer and I don't think the discussion adds much any more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation $X\sim \mathcal{D}$ means "The random variable $X$ has law (is distributed according to) the *probability distribution* $\mathcal{D}$.

$\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is [standard notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Notation) for the standard normal distribution over $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the continuous real-valued probability distribution with probability density function $f\colon x\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$.

Writing $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ thus makes sense. Writing $\sigma\mathcal{N}(0,1)=\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, for $\sigma>0$, also makes sense (as a common notation), since $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ is the Gaussian/Normal distribution with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$. *(Note that this is again a notation: you shouldn't think of it as the usual multiplication, more as a common shortcut for "$\sigma\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is the distribution of $\sigma X$, when $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$." The key is that the notation is common and quite standard.)*

Writing $x\sim(\mathcal{N}(0,1))^2$, however, does not (unless you want to use it as an *ad hoc* notation, in which case you need to *define* the new operation on probability distributions $\mathcal{D}\mapsto\mathcal{D}^2$ which maps a probability distribution to another legit probability distribution). What is $(\mathcal{N}(0,1))^2$? Is it a probability distribution, as it should?

---

In your specific case of the square of a Gaussian random variable, anyway, I'd recommend using the standard notation $X\sim\chi^2$, since by definition this is what the [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) is...

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! The reason is thus that it is *unusual* to define $D^2$ while it is *usual* to define $\sigma D$, with $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$, for $D$ a probability distribution.

Comment: Nice and clear answer (though I fail to understand how you do not conclude that the notation $\sigma\mathcal N(0,1)$ is faulty as well... except to mean a measure of mass $\sigma$, that is).

Comment: You see... You started perfectly, but then basically confused the OP.

Comment: @Did My bad, I added a line.

Comment: And now your edit got me curious: any reputable source for the notation $\sigma\mu$ to denote $P_{\sigma X}$ when $P_X=\mu$?

Comment: @Did Not in general, although I'll set out to find it this morning. I have seen it widely used for parametric distributions only, to be honest (of which the Gaussian is a prime example).

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is used to refer to a random variable. So $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ should be read: "$X$ is Normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$".

Though you can always invent notation if you find it useful, in this case it seem unhelpful to apply functions to the property itself. Instead the functions should be applied to the random variable which will then affect the property.

For instance,
$$\text{if } X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1),\;\text{ then }\;bX \sim \mathcal{N}(0,b^2).$$
Or, more generally
$$\text{if } X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2),\;\text{ then }\;a+bX \sim \mathcal{N}(a+b\mu,b^2\sigma^2).$$

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your first sentence. Different random variables may have the same distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: You may have $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, but $X$ and $Y$ refer to different random variables.

Comment: @Shuri2060 I am not claiming it is used to refer to a unique random variable, just "a" random variable. I think the statement is uncontroversial.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean. If $X$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are rvs, then what does $\sim$ mean in $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$? $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is a distribution or at least, simply refers to how $X$ is distributed.

Comment: @Shuri2060 $\sim$ should be read as "is distributed as".

Comment: Then clearly $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ refers to a distribution and not a rv?

Comment: @Shuri2060 I mean $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ refers to a random variable like an adjective refers to a substantive. I do not mean it is a rv itself.